# Android:largeHeap using art

Tags: android, runtime, heap-memory

according to the documantation:

Whether your application's processes should be created with a ***large Dalvik heap***...

What does it mean regarding ART (Android Runtime) ?
thx.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#largeHeap

Answer (score 1):

So,I found [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.companionfree.checker.largeheap) app on google play, that basiclly tells you which apps you have installed, had declared *largheap:true* in the manifest.
I tried it on kitkat (which is running dalvik), lolipop (which is running dalvik and ART), and marshmallow (which is running Art).
all of them showed results, which means that  *largheap:true* effects ART as well.